# How to show $\frac{|x|^{\delta}-(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}}{(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}} \sim \frac{1}{|x|^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $x\ \in \mathbb R^{n}$, then for $1<\delta<2$ how to show $$\frac{|x|^{\delta}-(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}}{(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}} \sim \frac{1}{|x|^2}.$$

It seems to me the numerator and the denominator have the same order. I also tried to foil by fractional binomial but still couldn't get it.

Comment: You have to explain what $\sim$ means. Maybe you are referring to $x\to0$, or to $|x|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $|x|$,$$(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}=|x|^\delta(1+|x|^{-2})^{\delta/2}\approx|x|^\delta\left(1+\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}\right)\implies\frac{|x|^\delta}{(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}}-1\approx-\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}.$$

Comment: I just found that your last arrow is not correct. $(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}\approx|x|^\delta\left(1+\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}\right)\implies \frac{(1+|x|^2)^{\delta/2}}{|x|^\delta}-1 \approx-\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}.$

Comment: @user012220 I was correct. Since $\frac{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^{\delta/2}}{|x|^\delta}\approx 1+\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}$, $\frac{|x|^\delta}{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^{\delta/2}}\approx 1-\frac{\delta}{2}|x|^{-2}$.